# Android : what metadata tags are needed for google signin

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add google signin capability to my app. I keep getting this runtime error:

```
Please verify that your manifest refers to the correct project ID. 
    
     For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
     https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_metadata_tags
```

I have registered my app here at[Google developers](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), added SHA1 key and received Client Id and secret key.

ClientID: 99######-f96#############.apps.googleusercontent.com

Here are the current metadata tags I have :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

I have set app_id in strings.xml to the ClientID

**Question 1 : Why do I keep getting asked to register the app as a game (as indicated by the link in the error) ?

Question 2: Am I setting the app_id to the right value (i.e. ClientID) ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by changing android:value in the metadata.

Initially I had
`<meta data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version android:value="@string/app_id" />`

app_id  set to clientId

Replaced it with :
`<meta data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version android:value="@integer/google_lay_services_version" />`